# How to get viewPager fragment at a specific index in FragmentStatePageAdapter from FragmentActivity?

Tags: android

I have setup my viewPager adapter like this:

```
private class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return EpisodeFragment.newInstance(id, episodeSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tabTitles.size();
    }
}
```

How can I find a fragment at a specific index from the FragmentActivity later on so that I can update the dataset or perform some other operation?

Answer (score 0):

During fragment transaction, FragmentStateAdapter creates tag in the following way:

```
this.mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.add(fragment, "f" + holder.getItemId())
.setMaxLifecycle(fragment, State.STARTED)
.commitNow();
```

As we can see from above, it's a combination of static string "f" and the value of *getItemId()* of the adapter's holder. The default *getItemId(int position)* inside FragmentStateAdapter is as follows:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long)position;
}
```

In this case, using the desired index value we can find the fragment at that specific index of the adapter as follows:

```
private EpisodeFragment getEpisodeFragment() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(itemId));
        if (fragment instanceof EpisodeFragment) {
            return (EpisodeFragment) fragment;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Where *getFragmentTag()* is defined as follows:

```
private static String getFragmentTag(long itemId) {
    return "f" + itemId;
}
```

If we want to assign specific **long** values as itemIds, we can assign those values in order to specify particular fragments at particular indices later on. We need to update the adapter to override *getItemId(int position)* as follows:

```
private class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return EpisodeFragment.newInstance(id, episodeSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tabTitles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        long fragmentTag;
        switch (position) {
            default:
            case 0:
                fragmentTag = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                fragmentTag = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                fragmentTag = 3;
                break;
        }
        return fragmentTag;
    }
}
```

Later on, we can find the desired fragment using these unique itemIds inside *getEpisodeFragment()*.